# Using AWK what's the best way to change an XML property

Tags: bash, awk

Using AWK how can I change the property enabled="true" to enabled="false" . I need to do this for all occurrences in the ResultCollector only.

Before:

```
 <asdjasl enabled="true">

    <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="View Results Tree" enabled="true">
    <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="View Results Tree" enabled="true">

 <asdjasl enabled="true">
```

After:

```
 <asdjasl enabled="true">

    <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="View Results Tree" enabled="false">
    <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="View Results Tree" enabled="false">

 <asdjasl enabled="true">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract xml tag value using awk command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054203/extract-xml-tag-value-using-awk-command)

Comment: Use the `system` function to launch a proper XML parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to change an XML property is with an XML processing tool, not a text processing tool. I'd use [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet)

```
xmlstarlet ed --inplace --update '//ResultCollector/@enabled' --value 'false' file.xml
```